# add html&javascript code in specific Wordpress page using Plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have html&javascript code that I want to add to a specific page through plugin when it installed, It's a simple Dropbox button so in this case should I use `add_filter()` function? but how to assign the page in the this image to the function [The page of the wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgnCL.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">

 <head>


 

     <!-- Dropbox library for importing the Dropbox button the webpage  -->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs"
         data-app-key="XXXXXXX"></script>
     


 </head>

 <body>

     

     <div class="dropbox_btn" style="  margin: auto !important; width: 50% !important; ">
         <!-- dropboxContainer is the id of Dropbox button which will be added in script.js file -->
         <div id="dropboxContainer"></div>
     </div>

      


 </body>
 </html>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your script in "init" hook to push JS or CSS.

```html
add_action('init','add_script');
public function add_script(){
$pages = !empty( $_GET['param'] ) ? $_GET['param'] : "";
if( "pages" == $pages && ! is_admin() ):
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    <?php
endif;
}
```

Comment: `$pages` variable prints empty string, btw the image in the question refer to real page so for exmaple if I have `Home` and `about` page I want to to insert this code only in Home or specific `div` in `Home`